# InputBarAccessoryView view does not show after Tab changed and back

Tags: ios, swift, chat, inputbaraccessoryview

I am using `InputBarAccessoryView` for an input accessory view of my chat controller. And `ChatViewController` is part of `UITabbarViewCntroller`.

When open my chat view first time `InputBarAccessoryView` show but when tab change and back, it is not showing.

Can you pease help to solve that issue?

Edited:

```
 var messageInputBar = InputBarAccessoryView()

 override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
        return messageInputBar
    }
```

Kamal

Comment: Add the code you've tried so far.

Comment: Question updated.